# react-datepicker not showing date correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I want to use `react-datepicker` with react but i don't know why not showing calendar correctly and I don't know why its not working and how can i fix it..

Here Is My Code

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import setHours from "date-fns/setHours";
import setMinutes from "date-fns/setMinutes";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";


function ProfileDetails() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 16)
  );

  return (
    <>
          <DatePicker
            selected={startDate}
            onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
            showTimeSelect
            includeTimes={[
              setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 17),
              setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 18),
              setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 19),
              setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 17),
            ]}
            dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
            inline
          />
    </>
)
}
```

and it just show dates in column direction like this Image..

[image: Image Of Output]

Comment: I would suspect that `react-datepicker.css` somehow isn't loaded - use the development tool to check that the expected styles is present.

Comment: i checked but as you said isn't loaded and i don't know why? :(

Comment: That depends on how the project is built (webpack?) and served. Posting your project directory structure and webpack config file (or whichever builder you're using) is necessary.

Comment: yeah i use webpack, and i use ```css module``` i mean if i want to use css styles i will import like this ```import styles from '..PATH'``` and when i want to set className 'btn1' for button i should use ```<button className={styles.btn1}> HELLO WORLD </button>``` ..

i don't know if it make problem

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely some issue with the css import or the CSS loaders. When i copy your code, its working correctly. But when i comment the css import, It behaves exactly like you mentioned above.

Comment: i use ```CSS MODULE``` i mean if i want to set class name btn1 for button i should use ``` import styles from '...PATH'``` then for add class name ```<button className={styles.btn1}> HELLO WORLD </button>```  its more about it, is there any problem using this module? (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)